# iOS exclude images from Whatsapp in Photos framework query

Tags: ios, whatsapp, photosframework

Is it possible to only query for PHAssets taken by the device camera? e.g. exclude images sent to you by Whatsapp.

I've tried the following without success:
1. Filter by asset mediaSubtype and sourceType
2. Filter by original filename as Whatsapp images typically use UUIDs in the filename.

Second option seems most promising maybe in combination with other meta data such as location (WhatsApp images usually strips this information out).

The filtering should ideally happen on PHAsset query and not need to call ImageManager.requestImage() for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out assets which are in the 'WhatsApp' album.

Here is a sample func you can use (swift 4.2):

```
static private func assetIsFromWhatsapp(_ asset : PHAsset) -> Bool {
    let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsContaining(asset, with: .album, options: nil)

    for index in 0..<collection.count  {
        let item = collection.object(at: index)
        if item.localizedTitle == "WhatsApp" {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```